# Oid.FromOidValue fails for DocumentEncryption Oid inside Docker-Container

Tags: c#, docker, encryption, .net-core, cryptography

I have a simple dotnet core codeblock that gets the Oid for the DocumentEncryption Oid-Value.

```
...
Oid.FromOidValue("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1" /*DocumentEncryption*/, OidGroup.EnhancedKeyUsage);
...
```

I've used the `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs` library in version 4.7.0 from Microsoft for this call.

Although this codeblock works on every windows system I deployed it on it does not run inside a windows docker container. I've tested the code with the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1` and `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1` images.

I get the following exception only from inside the container:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The OID value is invalid.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Oid.FromOidValue(String oidValue, OidGroup group)
```

Do I have to install something additionally into the container or am I missing something different?

Comment: Do you need the failure from the system not having the OID mapped to a display name? If not, you could just use `new Oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1", null)`, which only asks for the friendly-name when someone reads that property.

Comment: I use the codeblock to validate whether a ```X509Certificate2.Extension``` is or contains the Oid.

Comment: You can probably use the OID constructor instead of FromOidValue, then, and everything will just work.

Answer (score 0):

bartonjs said it right. The OID constructor instead of FromOidValue works just fine even in the docker container for windows.